# KeyChain Security command line tool works with find-internet-passwords but not find-generic-passwords

Tags: macos, command-line, keychain

Looking into using the command line tool for KeyChain. I am able to do a lot of the things through security; listing my multiple keychains, dumping them and setting defaults. Reading through tutorials and other postings I expect to find my passwords with

`security find-generic-password test`

But I get

> security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.

This won't work in my default keychain or login.keychain. However, I am able to find my passwords listed as 'internet' with find-internet-password command. Can anyone explain why or what I am doing wrong? Sites I've been reading is the man page and http://blog.macromates.com/2006/keychain-access-from-shell/,

Comment: One minor issue I ran into with find-generic-password: if the service name (-s parameter) contains a period ('.') ('example.com', for example), I can run add-generic-password successfully but can't find the value with find-generic-password.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generic passwords are identified by their Service and Account attributes. For example, to search for a password for account "bar" of the "foo" service, use

```
security find-generic-password -a foo -s bar -g
```

The `-g` option displays the value of the password at the end of the output.

The combination of service and account is guaranteed to uniquely identify a particular password. Other queries (comment, label, etc.) are possible, but they may match multiple passwords. `find-generic-password` displays only the first single matching item, which limits its usefulness for such queries.

Comment: What is the "Service" attribute? I don't see that label anywhere in the Keychain Access app on macOS Mojave 10.14.4. The metadata I see are "Name", "Kind", "Account", "Where", and "Comments". (I tried the obvious guess here, "Name", but that does not work.)

Comment: Keychain Access uses the "Where" label for the Service attribute.

Comment: Isn't `-s` the  service and `-a` the account? Seems they are inverted in the example.

Answer (score 3):

A more accurate and up to date answer would be to use `-w` instead of `-g` if you only need password. I've seen people using `-g` and parsing output using awk/perl to get the password field, which is not needed (anymore).
All you need to do is:

```
security find-generic-password -a foo -s bar -w
```

You may use `find-internet-password` instead of `find-generic-password` command depending on where your password is stored in keychain.